# Will my plugins be deleted, after reinstalling wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to install custom theme on wordpress, but have some errors while uploading it. now i want to reinstall wordpress from Cpanel file manager, will my plugins be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Your Theme and Plugins are stored within the `wp-content` folder, which is 'inside' WordPress.  So, yes, deleting WordPress would delete your Plugins and Themes.

**Solution:**

1. Download [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/).
2. Head over to `httpdocs > wp-content` folder, where you should see two folders entitled `plugins` and `themes`.
3. Drag these folders over to your Desktop (or wherever suits you).  What you are doing here, is creating a backup of your Theme and Plugins.
4. Go ahead and reinstall WordPress (To make a clean install, obviously remove all reference of WordPress and create a new MySql Database)
5. Once completed, simply access your website via Filezilla again.  Head back into `httpdocs > wp-content` and drag back over the your `plugins` and `themes` folder.

By following the above, you can delete WordPress, without losing your Theme files or Plugins.

Comment: No worries!  Any problems, just let me know.  Don't forget to 'Tick' the answer, if you found it helped you, so others know it works and could be of use to them too.  Best of luck! :-)